# Trying to push data to an array from a child component in vue.js but get TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

here is my child component

```
<b-container fluid class="bv-example-row">
        <b-row>
            <b-col cols="2" class="col-speaker">
                <b-row>
                    <b-input-group @keyup.enter="speakerInput" class="input-speaker">
                        <b-form-input  v-model="speaker" placeholder="speaker"></b-form-input>
                    </b-input-group>
                    {{speaker}}
                    <div class="w-100"></div>
                    <b-col>
                        <img class="caption-flag" src="../assets/flag (2).png">
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
            </b-col>
            <b-col>
                <div class="mainDashboard-caption">

                <h4 class="caption-timecode">{{start}}-{{end}}</h4>
                <b-row>
                    <b-col cols="11">
                        <b-form-textarea id="textarea1"
                                        v-model="userInput"
                                        placeholder="Enter something"
                                        :rows="3"
                                        :max-rows="6">
                        </b-form-textarea> 
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col>
                        <input class="caption-reviewed" type="checkbox"> 
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>

                <b-row class="row-buttons">
                    <b-col class="col-buttons">
                        <b-button :pressed="false" variant="outline-success" class="caption-merge-next">merge next</b-button>
                        <b-button :pressed="false" variant="outline-danger" class="caption-merge-prev">merge prev </b-button>
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
                </div>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MainDashboard',
    props: {
        start: { type: Number, required: true},
        end: { type: Number, required: true},
        text: '',
    },

    data () {
        return {
            userInput: '',
            speaker: '',
            plainText: false,
        }
    },

    methods: {
        speakerInput (speaker) {
        console.log(speaker)
            this.$emit('post-speaker', speaker)

        }

    }



}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

and here is my parent

```
<template>
    <div class="dashboardView">
        <div class="header">
            <MainHeader
            v-bind:fileName= this.fileName
            />
        </div>
        <div class="dashboard" v-for='caption in captions' :key='caption.end'>
            <MainDashboard 
            v-bind:start='caption.start'
            v-bind:end='caption.end' 
            v-bind:text='caption.text'

            @post-speaker="postSpeaker"                       
            />
        </div>
        <div class="footer">

        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import axios from 'axios'

import MainHeader from '../components/MainHeader.vue';
import MainDashboard from '../components/MainDashboard.vue';

export default { 
  name: 'dashboard',
  components: {
      MainDashboard,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      speakers: [],
      speaker:'',
      captions: [],
      text: '',
      fileName: '',
      result: this.getCookie('csrftoken')

    }

  },
  methods: {

    getCookie(key) {
      const regexp = new RegExp(`.*${key}=([^;]*)`);
      const result = regexp.exec(document.cookie);
      if(result) {
        return result [1]
      }
    },
    postSpeaker(speaker) {
      console.log(speaker)
      this.speakers.push(speaker)
      console.log(this.speakers)
      this.getCookie('csrftoken')
      axios.put('https://172.28.128.13/api/transcriptions/1/',{
          captions: {
            speakers: [this.speakers], captions: [this.captions]
          }
      },
       { 
         headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': this.result} 
        }) 
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
  },

  created() {
    axios.get(`https://172.28.128.13/api/transcriptions/?format=json`)
    .then(response => {
      // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
      this.captions = response.data.results[0].captions
      this.fileName = response.data.results[0].media_file
      this.speakers = response.data.results[0].captions.speakers
      console.log(this.fileName)
      console.log(this.captions)
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  },
  components: {
    MainHeader,
    MainDashboard,
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

im trying to emit the users input data in the child component to the parent component, and push it into speakers array. it breaks on `this.speakers.push(speaker)`in the parent component, and i get this error

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "post-speaker": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Im sure its something little that i'm doing wrong, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `this.errors.push(e)` is where the error is, you never define `errors` in `data()`

Comment: @derek Pollard i also missed that out. But the error is from the line `this.speakers.push(speaker)`

Comment: Checkout my answer and let me know if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the child component:

```
@keyup.enter="speakerInput"
```

If you notice, `speakerInput` expects you to pass `speaker` to it so it can ultimately emit the event to the parent.

Change it to:

```
@keyup.enter="speakerInput(speaker)"
```

Or, change `speakerInput` to use the data instead of expecting it to be passed:

```
methods: {
    speakerInput () {
        console.log(this.speaker)
        this.$emit('post-speaker', this.speaker)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @derek Pollard although your input didn't solve my problem, it made me gave me an 'AHA' moment to different ways you could go about emiting :)  everything was reaching to where it needed to go, but it was the data that was being imported was incorrect, as the shape of the data had changed, i wasn't getting the right set, hence it was undefined!! I just came back after the Christmas break, must still be holiday. rookie mistake! just goes to show you really do need to check every angle, even if you think you did! this is my first app using vue, seems v handy :) thanks for the help!